# Attaching Files to Emails in HTML/PHP Forms

Tags: php, html, email-attachments

I have a simple contact form where I want to add a file upload button.

How can I attach the uploaded in the email to whoever is receiving this

Codes below

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<?= base_url("../email.php") ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="row mb-n3">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required></div>
                            <div class="col-12 mb-3"><input name="attachment" type="file"></div>
                            <div class="col-12 mb-3"><input class="btn btn-primary px-5" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

email.php

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    
    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.f
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "admin@test.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New Message from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}?>
```

Your help is highly appreciated, please let know as to how can I get this sorted or fixed.

Thanks

Comment: Check your html form element attributes.

Comment: Also, you will need to create a multipart email then - which is a complex thing to do, manually. You should switch from using PHP's own `mail` function, to using a library such as PHPMailer - that comes with methods to properly create such a mail.

Comment: As for uploading files, the PHP manual has a page on [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), A full-featured email creation and transfer class for PHP

**Installtion:**

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

**Usage**

```
<?php

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```